# Получите года, сумма цифр которых равна 6

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить задачку.

Дан список с годами:

```
<ul>
<li>2001</li>
<li>2004</li>
<li>2021</li>
<li>2012</li>
<li>2035</li>
<li>2031</li>
```

Получите года, сумма цифр которых равна 6.

Нужно средствами JS решить данную задачу. Я ещё в процессе изучения языка и поэтому застрял на пару дней уже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul>li')] // получаем все li
     .map(({textContent}) => textContent.trim())      // извлекаем текст
     .filter((text) =>                                // фильтруем по условию
       [...text]                                      // разбиваем на цифры
         .map((v) => Number.parseInt(v))              // ... и переводим в number 
         .reduce((a, v) => a += v, 0) === 6           // складываем и проверяем условие
      )
console.log(items)
```

```html
<ul>
<li>2001</li>
<li>2004</li>
<li>2021</li>
<li>2012</li>
<li>2035</li>
<li>2031</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Немного сложно для меня конечно, но постараюсь разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Function to compute the sum of digits in a number
function sumOfDigits(num) {
  let sum = 0;

  // Keep adding the last digit of the number to the sum and remove it until there are no digits left
  while (num) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num = Math.floor(num / 10);
  }

  return sum;
}

// Initial list of years
const yearsList = document.querySelector('ul');
const years = Array.from(yearsList.children).map(li => parseInt(li.textContent));

// Filter the list of years to include only the ones whose sum of digits is 6
const filteredYears = years.filter(year => sumOfDigits(year) === 6);

console.log('Result: ' + filteredYears); // [2004, 2031]
```

```html
<ul>
<li>2001</li>
<li>2004</li>
<li>2021</li>
<li>2012</li>
<li>2035</li>
<li>2031</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Хм, подозрительно похоже на ответ от ChatGPT...

Comment: @ΝNL993 это вас так смутили комментарии в коде?

Comment: Да, к тому же на английском, мы же как ни как в **русском** сообществе, а не английском.